# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined; when nodeIntegration set to false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I am trying to create an application using Electron, React and TypeScript (and my idea seems to be a nightmare to me now). I am using electron-prebuilt-compile to transpile my code.
My intention is to keep nodeIntegration as false. However, if I do that, it shows me error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at index.html:inline_0.js:2

I have tried to add a few babel presets but those are not helping me. I have added CommonJS preset as well there. But it still fails.

Reason behind keeping nodeIntegration false is that I do not want it to be accessible in renderer.js because of security hazards it brings with it.

//.compilerc

```
"env": {
    "development": {
      "application/javascript": {
        "presets": [
          [
            "env",
            {
              "targets": {
                "electron": "4.1.3"
              }
            }
          ],
          "react",
          "es2016-node5"
        ],
        "plugins": [
          "react-hot-loader/babel",
          "dynamic-import-node",
          ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs", {
      "allowTopLevelThis": true
    }],
          "transform-async-to-generator",
          "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"
        ],
        "sourceMaps": "inline"
      },
      "text/html": {
        "pretty": true
      }
    },
```

//package.json

```
{
  "name": "master-dashboard",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Master Dashboard",
  "main": "app/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron .",
    "postinstall": "electron-rebuild"
  },
  "keywords": [
  ],
  "author": "Kaustav Sarkar",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^4.1.3",
    "electron-compile": "^6.4.4",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.2",
    "electron-prebuilt-compile": "^4.0.0",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.8.4",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.8.2"
  }
```

}

//index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>My   Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"         href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="master"></div>
</body>
<script type="application/javascript">
    require('./renderers/renderer')
</script>

</html>
```

//index.js gist

```
const createWindow = () => {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        center: true,
        resizable: true,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegrationInWorker: false,
            nodeIntegration: false,
            show: false
        }
    });
    win.maximize();
    win.webContents.openDevTools();

win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    slashes: true,
    protocol: 'file'
}), { "extraHeaders": "Cache-Control: no-cache\n" });
```

Comment: nodeIntegration is way to enable use node's feature (`require` commonjs module loading) in renderer process. You can't use commonjs require without it.

Comment: I agree. I was thinking if we could perhaps use Babel presets to convert import statement to browser comprehendible statement

Comment: You can use preload script to (re-)introduce these kinda symbols even when you have node integration turned off (if you feel like it worth the hassle). See [example](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/process#event-loaded)

Comment: @pergy , can you please give me some reference on how can we use preload.js in electron app as I am getting error Uncaught ReferenceError: Require is not defined , thanks

Comment: @Enthu additionally to the api docs link in my comment study https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start as an example

Comment: @pergy thanks got an idea how the preload.js has to be included, last query how can I include require.js using preload.js, that would be great.